# epoll_wait missing EPOLLIN events on a TCP socket fd

Tags: sockets, io, linux-kernel, kernel, epoll

On the server side: I am using epoll_wait to monitor the possible read IO on a TCP socket.
On the client side: I have a single threaded app to write to the socket that's connected to the server.

The problem is, sometimes epoll_wait doesn't recognize there is new IO to read even after a new message is sent from the client. (I confirmed the message is indeed received by the server using wireshark) So the client is hanging waiting on the response from server. **BUT: if I kill the client connection, epoll_wait does get notified!**

Originally I am using EPOLLET and thought it would be a problem. But this issue still exists after removing EPOLLET.

Is there any tool that I can use to debug this? (e.g, outside of server process, to confirm that there is IO on the server socket queue but epoll_wait doesn't process it?) Any thought or guidance on how to debug this would be appreciated.

Comment: You could compile your own kernel and add debug logs at appropriate places, if you can read and understand kernel code. Also, you could use strace. There are also some newer kernel tracing tools, google it and you will find a lot of useful stuff. But first of all, read through epoll manpage and look at a few more code examples to make sure you use the api the right way.

Comment: You could provide your code for comment. Otherwise I don't see how your question can possibly be answered, short of a known kernel bug.